# Looking for ways to avoid 'List index out of range error'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I made a script that works, but only if I know how many lines locations.txt will have.
Is there any way to keep the script working regardless of the amount of lines? (I am expecting 1 to 12 lines maximum).

```
locline1 = content[1]
locline2 = content[2]
```

Works great when there are two lines in the list of locations. If there is only one location then I need to change the script to;

```
locline1 = content[1]
locline2 = content[1]
```

That workaround avoids any errors and lets it run, providing duplicate results which is better than nothing.

I tried to make another script that will check how many lines there are and make appropriate replacements to the first script. It ran without errors but the replacements weren't made, I can investigate that later if that is a decent route to take.

In main script

```
import varilen
exec(open("varilen.py").read())
```

Varilen.py below;

```
file = open("locations.txt","r")
Counter = 1
Content = file.read()
CoList = Content.split("\n")

for i in CoList:
 if i:
  Counter += 1
  if Counter < 2:
   cr1test = open('amazing727p6.py', mode='w', encoding='UTF-8') 
   cr1 = (re.sub(r'content[2]', 'content[1]', cr1test, count=0, flags = re.DOTALL))
```

More detail about the main script (just in case it makes a difference);

The script reads a base file, finds the names of locations in there and writes one copy of each of those on the lines of a new file locations.txt.

Later the script reads the lines of locations.txt and assigns these to those lines.
locline1 = content[1]
locline2 = content[2]

Make a replacement to take out everything except for the location name on each line.
Make a new file saved as that (location name + _results.txt), then search the base file for lines containing that location name and write those lines to that location's results.txt

For example;
Search this base file

```
abc!New york aaaaaa a
gg3aa!New York aa bbbb
g44!Chicago au4s a3e
```

Make locations.txt

```
"New York
"Chicago
```

Make "New York results.txt" copy matching lines from base file and format columns.

```
abc!    New york aaaaaa a
gg3!aa  New York aa bbbb
```

It's all working but if locline12 = content[12] and there isn't a 12th line in locations.txt then it doesn't work at all.

Not asking for a specific answer although that's always welcome. I am just asking how should I try to go about fixing/improving the script in regards to this issue.

**

### EDIT:

**

This will provide more detail,
This is the code before the line throwing the error;

```
rmuser4 = Path('lpgetandremoveuserresults1.txt', encoding='UTF-8').read_text()
rmuser5 = open('locations.txt', mode='w+')
rmuser6 = (re.sub(r'\[H.+', '', rmuser4))
print(rmuser6, file= rmuser5)
rmuser5.close()

lines_seen = set()

with open("locations.txt", "r+", encoding='UTF-8') as fqqw:
    dqqw = fqqw.readlines()
    fqqw.seek(0)
    for iqqw in dqqw:
        if iqqw not in lines_seen:
            fqqw.write(iqqw)
            lines_seen.add(iqqw)
    fqqw.truncate()
fqqw.close()

fileyu = open('locations.txt', encoding='UTF-8')
content = fileyu.readlines()


locline1 = content[1]
locline2 = content[2]
locline3 = content[3]
locline4 = content[4]
locline5 = content[5]
locline6 = content[6]
locline7 = content[7]
locline8 = content[8]
locline9 = content[9]
locline10 = content[10]
locline11 = content[11]
locline12 = content[12]
```

So it makes the locations.txt document, depending on which base file is being used it might have only 1 line or 12 lines.

Below is part of the code that comes after, only the code using locline5 / content[5] is shown in this post, but the script has nearly identical code for each 1 through 12, not just 5.

```
filenameline5 = (re.sub(r'"(.+?Events).+', '\\1', locline5, count=0, flags = re.DOTALL))
loc5new = open('%s results.txt' % filenameline5, mode='w+', encoding='UTF-8') 
print(filenameline5, file= loc5new)
loc5new.close()

filei5 = Path('%s results.txt' % filenameline5, mode='w+').read_text()

addq5rep = (re.sub(r'(.+?) .+', '"\\1', filei5, count=1, flags = re.A))
addq5base = open('search for %s.txt' % filenameline5, mode='w+', encoding='UTF-8')

print(addq5rep, file= addq5base)
addq5base.close()

list_file = open('search for %s.txt' % filenameline5)
search_words = []
for word in list_file:
    search_words.append(word.strip())
list_file.close()

matches = []

master_file = open('readable_export.txt', encoding='UTF-8')
for line in master_file:    
    current_line = line.split()    
    for search_word in search_words:       
        if search_word in current_line:           
            matches.append(line)            
            break
master_file.close()
new_file = open('%s results.txt' % filenameline5, 'w+')
for line in matches:
    new_file.write(line)
new_file.close()
```

So the problem is that if locations.txt is created with only 3 lines, the later code trying to use locline4 through locline12 will ruin everything. But changing the code like this would fix it (if locations.txt has 3 lines).

```
locline1 = content[1]
locline2 = content[2]
locline3 = content[3]
locline4 = content[1]
locline5 = content[1]
locline6 = content[1]
locline7 = content[1]
locline8 = content[1]
locline9 = content[1]
locline10 = content[1]
locline11 = content[1]
locline12 = content[1]
```

I'm trying to fix it so that I don't need to manually make these edits depending on how many lines I am expecting locations to have.

Thank you

Comment: What does the main script look like?

Comment: Where is the code that is actually throwing the error? The `locline12 = content[12]` that you mentioned?

Comment: Usually the solution to this is to loop over the items, rather than hard-coding indexes.

Comment: What's the point of `exec(open("varilen.py").read())`? Isn't that basically what `import varilen` does?

Comment: How do you determine that the name of the city is "New York" and not "New", alternatively, how do you determine the name of the city is "Chicago" rather than "Chicago au4s"?

Comment: @not_speshal The error mentioned the line specifically that (only) says locline2 = content[2]. That happened of course when locations.txt only had one line. I appreciate everyone's comments, thank you. I tried to update last night but was not able to until today, more code has been added to the post.
I only started working on this a few weeks ago and have no knowledge of how to actually code, I put this 1500 line script together and got it working by using posts/comments on this site. My apologies for such inefficient ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

Well for a small improvement, using len(CoList) will give you the number of lines in location.txt

Comment: TY for the response
I was thinking breaking the script up into 3 pieces
Part 1: read base, created locations.txt execute part 2.
Part 2: read locations.txt and count how many lines are in it. Also make replacements to part 3 as necessary, if the count shows locations only has 11 lines instead of 12, then change the part 3 script: locline 12 = content[12] to locline12 = content[1] and so on. Then execute part 3.
Part 3: run the rest of the script, making new documents, searching basefile, writing matching lines.
So if locations.txt only has 1 line then part 2 will make 11 changes to part 3

Comment: Typically for things like this I would use the while loop python has. In the past I've used a while(!EOF) (I don't have my code with me at this time unfortunately to show how exactly it's implemented.) I would use a while(File is open and not end of file), read that data and output it to whichever file it belongs in(or save it in a list if you need too)

Comment: Thank you @SSmith I'll look into that! I appreciate the tips

Answer (score 0):

Even you can user the if condition in side your for loop to check \n value like

```
    if line != "\n":
        line_count += 1
```